# How to load css in the footer in function.php with wordpress theme

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I was trying to move the load of my style.css in the footer of my wordpress theme.
I have already done something similar with 2 js files and it works fine, they load in the footer:

```
function my_init() {
    if (!is_admin()) {
        wp_deregister_script('jquery');
        wp_register_script('jquery', 'http://www.studionews24.com/wp-content/themes/network/js/jquery.min.js', false, '1.3.2', true);
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

        // load a JS file from my theme: js/theme.js
        wp_enqueue_script('my_script', 'http://www.studionews24.com/wp-content/themes/network/js/menu-resp.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
    }
}
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

Now i was trying to move in the footer also the style.css, and keep only some inline css rules in the `<head>` tag. I have tried wp_enqueue_style but it seems doesn't work well for me.

Someone could help me for find a smart solution?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_init');
```

or since you have add parameter `true` in your script callback function:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_init');
```

You may go here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com if you need help around wordpress programming.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
add_action('init', 'my_init');
```

with

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'my_init', 100);
```